# Error with new unit test target: error: No such file or directory - old dSYM file cannot be overwritten

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, dwarf, dsym

I just added a brand new unit test target to my project and am getting the following error:

> error: No such file or directory - old dSYM file cannot be
>   overwritten:      old:
>   '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-ajbgwuvijemxwlgvdalbjlgirypy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyProject'

Anyone have any ideas?